# How to use 'cut' with null delimiter

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash

This question basically is exactly the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848426/how-to-cut-on-null) question in Stackoverflow.

Using the syntax of `cut` the specification `cut -d '' file` should actually work and (given the answers to the question) it seems to work on Linux systems. However, on Mac Os X I get `cut: bad delimiter`.

My question is: **is there a way to specify a null delimiter in `cut` on Mac Os X?**

(I know that one could just something else than `cut` but I am just wondering now ...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard `cut` on macOS doesn't support this, but you can get the GNU version (which does) by installing `coreutils` through [Homebrew](http://brew.sh).